# OpenCV HOG People Detection - How to tell if person detected is the same person as previously detected?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm new to OpenCV and I am trying to write a program that detects people in a video. I have this code that is a variation of the peopledetect example.

```
def inside(r, q):
    rx, ry, rw, rh = r
    qx, qy, qw, qh = q
    return rx > qx and ry > qy and rx + rw < qx + qw and ry + rh < qy + qh


def draw_detections(img, rects, thickness=1):
    for x, y, w, h in rects:
        # the HOG detector returns slightly larger rectangles than the real objects.
        # so we slightly shrink the rectangles to get a nicer output.
        pad_w, pad_h = int(0.15 * w), int(0.05 * h)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x + pad_w, y + pad_h),
                      (x + w - pad_w, y + h - pad_h), (0, 255, 0), thickness)

def find_people(img):
        hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
        hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
        img = frame
        if img is None:
            return None
        #  print('Failed to load image file:', fn)
        #  continue
        # except:
        #  print('loading error')
        #  continue

        found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(
            img, winStride=(10, 10), padding=(32, 32), scale=1.05)
        found_filtered = []
        for ri, r in enumerate(found):
            for qi, q in enumerate(found):
                if ri != qi and inside(r, q):
                    break
                else:
                    found_filtered.append(r)
                draw_detections(img, found)
                draw_detections(img, found_filtered, 3)
                print('%d (%d) found' % (len(found_filtered), len(found)))
        return img

if __name__ == '__main__':


    import argparse
#   import itertools as it
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
                    help="path to the (optional) video file")
    ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
                    help="max buffer size")
    # ap.add_argument("-f", "--blur-faces", action='blur_faces',
    #        help="Blur the faces contained in the video")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    print(help_message)

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

 # keep looping
    while True:
      # grab the current frame
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

  # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
  # then we have reached the end of the video
      # if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
      #    break
        img = find_people(frame)

        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        #Waitkey must be called for something to show up on the screen
        #It gives the computer time to process the image.
        cv2.waitKey(30)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code finds people and draws a rectangle around them. How would I go about finding out if the person detected is the same person as was detected in a previous frame of the video? Or how could I find out if the person the HOG detects has previously been detected?

I know that I could save the locations that the HOG finds and compare to see which are the around the same but I don't think this method would work if the person in the video left the frame and then returned because they would be treated as a new person. Is it possible to associate the colors of their clothes with specific people recognized and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I am doing something similar because I am "tracking" the persons appearing in a video to count incoming/ongoing people in a shop.
To tell if this is the same person I am just using the position of the detection and I compare it with the rectangles found in the previous detections. 
That works quite good except when I have false positive and false negative.